# Command line live logging tail not finding gRPC module

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to do:

```
> gcloud alpha logging tail
```

and it gives me the error message:

```
Please ensure that the gRPC module is installed and the environment is correctly configured. Run:
  sudo pip3 install grpcio
and set:
  export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES=1
```

But I've definitely done both of these. The pip install says this:

```
> sudo -H pip3 install grpcio
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio in /Library/Python/3.9/site-packages (1.54.0)
```

Is there anything else that might cause the error? All the othe gcloud commands seem to work, so the auth and project selection is all set up fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to

1. Re-run `sudo python3 install grpcio`
2. Run `gcloud beta logging tail`

also try to add the `export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES=1` command to your .bashrc (or equivalent) file:

Comment: Nope. Does not work. Installing python packages with sudo is no longer allowed: `sudo pip3 install grpcio`: `error: externally-managed-environment ... This environment is externally managed...See PEP 668` blah blah blah. Not an answer. Why can't Google get their CLI to work? Everything with Google Cloud is just so broken and complicated. Wonder it works for anyone.